# How to python version control?Do I need setuptools if I use git?

Tags: python, git, setuptools

Python has it own distutils which I have limited knowledge with. What I know is:

- it use **MANIFEST.in** to do file ignorance/inclusion.
- it is doing so `python setup.py sdist`
  then i will have a gzipped  dist

And I found there is a https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools-git that use **git**, but I don't see how it related to git, it is not even showing any git command in the doc.

My question is, do I simply remove **MANIFEST.in** if I use git?
or there should be a elegant pythonic way to use **setuptools-git**

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> setuptools-git is a plugin for setuptools that enables git integration. Once installed, Setuptools can be told to include in a package distribution all the files tracked by git. This is an alternative to explicit inclusion specifications with MANIFEST.in.

its purpose is to replace the MANIFEST.in with the files you ignore in the .gitignore
you dont have to use this plugin unless you want that the .gitignore will replace youre MANIFEST.in